# Ext-Js how to modify Combo box display for selection

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

In my selection model items can be strings, integers or html data.
Like "Testing", "1234" or "".

When the item is in html , my selection model is rendering html, I am not sure how to avoid it. 
[image: Selected item]

[image: Shown while selecting]

THank you 
PS: I am currently using EXT JS 3.4

Comment: I know how to unescapehtml, not sure how to use it here though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own template and use it for display each item in the dropdown list.

`Ext.form.ComboBox` component have `tpl` config property where you can set template string, or Ext.XTemplate instance to use to display each item in the dropdown list.

In this template you can encode HTML in display values.

For encoding HTML in Ext JS you can use [`Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-htmlEncode) function.

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class="x-combo-list-item">{[fm.htmlEncode(values.displayText)]}</div>',
'</tpl>'
);

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    mode: 'local',
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: [
            'myId',
            'displayText'
        ],
        data: [[1, '<b>item1</b>'], [2, '<i>item2<i>']]
    }),
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    valueField: 'myId',
    displayField: 'displayText',
    tpl: tpl  
});
```